# Grub boot screen always loads regardless of drive selected

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've looked around for a solution to this already but can't find one, I hope it isn't answered already elsewhere.

It's more of an annoyance... my PC has one 250gb SSD and one 2TB HDD. My SSD has Windows 10 installed, and I recently installed Ubuntu onto my 2TB HDD.

Now when I boot my PC, the BIOS requests I select which drive to boot on, which is expected. However, regardless of whether I select my SSD or HDD, I always get the purple Grub boot screen. At first, Windows 10 wasn't available - after a panic attack (thought I'd somehow overwritten Windows), I updated the grub following some great advice on here and now Windows 10 is again available for me to access, and all the partitions to me look as expected in Disk Management.

Why is Ubuntus Grub boot screen loading when I'm choosing my SSD? It's not the end of the world having to select Windows 10 like that but I'd rather understand what's going on and preferably have it boot to Windows 10 immediately upon choosing the SSD, and immediately pointing to Ubuntu when I select the 2TB HDD.

I am.. enthusiastic about stuff like this but ultimately a noob so do bear with me.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You probably installed grub on both disks.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a safe way to remove grub off the ssd without risking any changes to my Windows partition, please?

Comment: Yes. This --^. It probably happened when you were updating GRUB to see Win 10.

Comment: @DeadMerrick - Unplug the SATA cable from the Ubuntu HDD, and then run the repair MBR commands from Windows

Comment: But is Windows installed in UEFI or MBR mode?

Comment: I think its UEFI but I'd rather check, I haven't dual booted before and its not something I'm familiar with. Anyway to check? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a drive it will start the boot manager installed on the drive.  You say it isn't the end of the world, which suggests you can live with it, but just want to know what happened and how you can change it.

**What happened**

You have installed Grub on both drives.  Most likely this happened during your "panic attack" when you followed the advice to see Windows again.  The person providing support knew that you would see Windows if Grub was functioning properly.  The instructions most likely fixed/intalled Grub on the a second time on the alternate drive and you can now see Windows and have the choice.

**How to boot directly to Windows without Grub**

Reinstall a Windows Boot Manager on the Drive with your Windows install, then select that one for your Boot when you want to skip Grub.

If running the process cause you to not be able to see Grub again on either drive, you can install Grub again, but this time be very particular to install it on the desired drive... most likely the one you have Ubuntu installed on.

When installing Grub, you specify the target drive as an argument:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Change **/sdX** to be the drive you are installing Grub to.  The `/dev/sda` will most be your first first drive.  The `/dev/sdb` will be your secondary drive.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for all the help. I'll look into how to put Windows Boot Manager onto the SSD. I definitely didn't specify any drives during the grub updates, so that makes perfect sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @DeadMerrick If you have got the right answer then please check the answer to mark it as an accepted answer. It will be a better compliment than a thanks. :)